# Update paginator laravel in ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel, paginator

I create a page on which there is a table with a paginator. I post a request to specify the output of rows from the database for insertion into the table. However, the paginator remains old. How should I change it?
Get a request for a new page or insert all the HTML code that comes from the controller is not satisfied.

Code view:

```
<table class="table table-bordered text-center table-hover" id="table_list">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="id_card" value=""></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @if($dats)
            @foreach($dats as $data)
                <tr>
                    <td><div class="help" data-id="{{ $data['id'] }}"> {{$data['id']}}</div></td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        @endif
    </tbody>
</table>
{{ $dats->links() }} // After completing the ajax, the link remains old and allows you to navigate through the old table
```

Js code in view:

```
$('#id_card').on('keyup', function(){ // search
            value = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/home',
                data: {
                    search: value,
                    code: 1,
                    _token: '{{csrf_token()}}'
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#table_list').empty();
                    $('#table_list').append(data);  // update table 
                     //update paginator links
                },
                error: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                }
            })
        })
```

Code controller

```
public function search(Request $request){
$models= Model::where('table','LIKE','%'.$request->input('search').'%')->paginate(4);
$str = "";
foreach($models as $model){
    $str .= '<tr>'.
            '<td>'. $model["id"].'</td>'.
            '</tr>';
}
print($str);
return;
```

}

Comment: You might need to provide some code to support your question, it is not making much sense to me.

Comment: For me, English is not my native language, sorry.
Added the code, which would be more understandable, what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Laravel 5, you could do it by changing your controller to something like this.

```
public function search(Request $request){
    $models= Model::where('table','LIKE','%'.$request->input('search').'%')->paginate(4);
    $str = "";
    foreach($models as $model){
        $str .= '<tr>'.
                '<td>'. $model["id"].'</td>'.
                '</tr>';
    }

    return response()->json([
        'rows' => $str,
        'links' => $models->render()
    ], 200);

}
```

In your ajax response, render the links with `$('ul.pagination').replaceWith(data.links);`

eg.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/home',
    data: {
        search: value,
        code: 1,
        _token: '{{csrf_token()}}',
        page: page
    },
    success: function (data) {
        $('#table_list').empty();
        $('#table_list').append(data.rows);  // update table 
        $('ul.pagination').replaceWith(data.links); // update links
    },
    error: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: For what? I wanted to delete the old pagination on the view and add a new one after changing the table.Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Ah, ok, misunderstood your question. I have updated my answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: I did not expect an answer and made a request with the help of the Get, but I like your option much more. Thank you)

Comment: I tried your code, but it returns an empty value to me.

Comment: What version of laravel? You could try '''->links()'''

Comment: Specify returns an empty value in the links.
I tried to use the ->links() method instead of the ->render(), but the result is the same. My version 5.5.34